# Inter-node communication

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

How can inter-node communication be handled using Dataflow Java SDK. Meaning, does owner of job submitted to Dataflow pipeline, have fine grained control over cluster maintenance and scheduling?

Seems like this is auto-managed for user, as Dataflow uses container VM which register with Kubernetes API server.

If ability to influence cluster scheduling is needed, I see two possibilities -  a) access to raw sockets (if available, how?) or 
b) inject code for inter-node communication like 'Akka' in Spark. For this,  would one develop user defined functions in Transforms or PCollections or either based on need?

Comment: im no expert but AFAIK inter node communication is not possible and mentioned in the documentation. look at google dataproc.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the question, Dataflow is a fully managed service, so it should not be necessary to manage the cluster at all. As a result, there is no API for influencing cluster scheduling, etc.

If you need to communicate data between transforms, you could take a look at [side inputs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#side-inputs). This allows you to broadcast a PCollection and use it as an additional input to a DoFn.

If you can share a more concrete use case we could provide more details on what is available.